# What's the use of ApnsService.start in notnoop java-apns? I can push msg with push method without start()

Tags: java, push, apple-push-notifications

```
                  sv = APNS.newService()
            .withCert("./dev.p12", "pwd") 
            .withSandboxDestination()
            .build();
```

I just use sv.push(token, payload) without sv.start(), it seems that it worked well.
So what's the use of start() and stop()? Should I add them in my code?

Comment: I've checked the source code, it seems that the service will have already started when I get the instance in notnoop apns. And if the connection fails, it will try 3 times to reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not requested for a non-blocking / queued or pooled APNS service, so the default Impl returned by the builder is `ApnsServiceImpl` whose `start()` method does nothing.

```
    public void start() {
}
```

Other Impls like the `MinaAdaptor` do have some init code on `start()`.

```
public void start() {
    cf = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
    cf.awaitUninterruptibly();
}
```

Comment: @user2126346 It depends on the number of connections you need and where the bottleneck is. The pooled service maintains a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApnsConnection>`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadocs](http://notnoop.github.io/java-apns/apidocs/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsService.html):

> **void start():** Starts the service. The underlying implementation may
>   prepare its connections or datastructures to be able to send the
>   messages. This method is a blocking call, even if the service
>   represents a Non-blocking push service. Once the service is returned,
>   it is ready to accept push requests.

In your case it seems like the service is already started. Try `sv.stop()` then `sv.push()` what happens? (It should fail)

Or @Deepak's explanation can be valid too

Comment: I wrote code like:  service.stop();
    service.push(token, payload); And the msg can be pushed successfully. So maybe push method will auto call start()